# Effect of Syndra's ultimate on Nocturne/Sivir's spellshield?

Tags: league-of-legends

Considering that Syndra has 4-5 spheres in the field then she casts ult on Sivir.

> Unleashed Power has a brief cast time before it activates, but Syndra does not have to remain in place while the spheres apply their damage.

To quote another from http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Syndra#Unleashed_Power

> Spell shields will only block the damage of a single sphere.

I want to know the difference if Sivir managed to cast the spellshield **before** Syndra casts her ultimate and **after**.

- Before: Will the damage of the entire ultimate get blocked? Or just the first sphere?
- After: Will it still block a single sphere when it was already casted (since Zed/Zilean's time-delayed damage procs even after the spellshield was casted)?

Answer (score 5):

For spellshields a Syndra ultimate is basically just a bunch of spells fired in rapid succession. This means that a single orb will be blocked while the other ones just pass through.

As an example: You are Sivir and you use the shield before Syndra uses her ult on you. 4 of the 5 orbs will pass while the first orb gets blocked.

If you use your shield after Syndra has already started casting her ultimate, 2 of the orbs will damage you, one is blocked and the other 2 will damage you again. So basically **there is always only One blocked orb**.

The same rules apply for banshees and Nocture spellshield.

To prevent burst it's still better to use the shield on one of her other abilities (or best: her stun) since these deal more damage than a single blocked ultimate orb.

Comment: Normally you do not use your spellshields to prevent burst but to prevent CC